# How to properly scale Image components to screen percentages?

Tags: unity, gui, transformation

Let's take a `Sprite`. I have two methods for retrieving an orthographic size of the screen:

```
public static float Width(){
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    float height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
    float width = height * cam.aspect;
    return width;
}

public static float Height(){
    Camera cam = Camera.main;
    float height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
    return height;
}
```

Now, for the `Sprite`, I have an extension method:

```
public static void ScreenPercentWidth(this SpriteRenderer renderer, float percent){
    renderer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
        Screen.Width() / 100f * percent / renderer.sprite.bounds.size.x,
        renderer.transform.localScale.y,
        renderer.transform.localScale.z
    );

}
```

Which I can use like `sprite.ScreenPercentWidth(50f)` and it works.

What about a `RectTransform`/`Image`? Is there any way that I could create similar methods, so I can scale the `Image` like in the above example?

Comment: Any answer to this will need more information. Do you want to maintain the aspect ratio of objects or does that not matter? (For example, do you want a square to remain a square?) If so, you need to decide things like whether you want to crop the output to the same aspect ratio on all screens or just show more background on wider screens.

Answer (score 1):

`Canvas` and `RectTransform` should do all the heavy lifting for you (more accurately, `CanvasScaler`). Usually, I set the UI Scale Mode on the canvas to Scale With Screen Size. You can define a "reference resolution" which is the screen size the UI layout and images are designed for.

To have a RectTransform take up half of the canvas's width, (assuming it is a direct child of the canvas) you would set the x value of the anchor properties in the inspector. To align it to the left edge of the canvas, set min x anchor to 0 and max to 0.5. To center it, set min to 0.25 and max to 0.75. After these are set, zero out the horizontal elements in the position section (x,width). Their names may have changed at this point though.

Comment: Relevant [UI Basic Layout](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html) and [UI- Support Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)